# Margin/Padding on Post title when text wraps

Tags: css, title, word-wrap

http://www.gmnc.org/

Posts in right sidebar- when h4 heading wraps, the CSS doesn't seem to know there are 2 lines- and the margin/padding at the bottom sets itself from the first line. I can mess with the CSS, but can't seem to get it to space itself properly. Any ideas?

Here's what I mean: https://img.skitch.com/20121015-cqwmjpt6ct353bxrjde4hmgysu.jpg

Thank you!!!

Comment: can you post the CSS you're currently using as an example?

Comment: Do you mind to share some code?

Comment: #sidebar p {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
style.css (line 109)
p {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

Comment: #sidebar h4 {
    color: #5679A2;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
style.css (line 107)
h4 {
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em;
    padding: 0.25em 0;
}

Comment: I can get rid of the padding on top of the paragraph, which helps some- and I can edit the "line-height" but none of that really solves the problem...

Comment: See Lrdwhyt's answer below, it looks fine when you remove the height of 1.25em

Answer (score 2):

You have a set height of 1.25em in line 29 of screen.css for h4s.

If you remove that, the next element should base its position off of where the text ends, rather than where the h4's height tells it to end.

Comment: Yes! you're so right!- I was changing the style.css rather than the screen.css!  THANK YOU SO MUCH!